# Datastax DSE JMX Configuration

Tags: datastax-enterprise

Running dse 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS.  Using Oracle Java 8.  Configured jmxremote.access, jmxremote.password and management.properties.  JMX connections for 'nodetool -u xxxx -h xx.xx.xx.xx status' is working.

Getting an error when using a dsetool command:

dsetool autojt

"One or more JMX beans have not been registered. Has this node finished starting up?
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp:type=core,name=JobTrackerManager"

What configuration needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the cassandra node you are looking to communicate with running an Analytics workload?

Check `/etc/default/dse` to see if `HADOOP_ENABLED` is 1, ([doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/startStop/refDseServ.html)).

I tested this locally with 4.8.3 and ccm and did not observe the error when using the hadoop workload, but I do see it otherwise:

Without hadoop workload:

```sh
ccm create -n 1 -v 4.8.3 dse483 -dse -s
ccm node1 dsetool autojt
One or more JMX beans have not been registered. Has this node finished starting up?
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp:type=core,name=JobTrackerManager
```

With hadoop workload enabled:

```sh
ccm create -n 1 -v 4.8.3 dse483 --dse
ccm node1 setworkload hadoop
ccm node1 start
ccm node1 dsetool autojt
ccm node1 dsetool listjt
DC                             JobTracker   
Analytics-ACTUAL               127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was happening on a HADOOP_ENABLED=1 node.  I turned off CFS_ENABLED, restarted dse, and the problem went away.